# Octopus AWS Web.config transformation

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, octopus-deploy

Is there any way to scope octopus variable per EC2 instance?

Scenario: We have multiple instances in AWS auto auto scale group and we want to have different value of a variable on all of the EC2 instances. Is there any way to scope octopus variable per EC2 instance.

Comment: 1) Do you need to scope these values per each EC2 instance or the same for all EC2 instances?

2) You said you are auto-scaling. How are you registering these VMs into Octopus when each one gets provisioned?

Comment: 1. I need these values per each EC2 instance.
2. This is done through PS script once the instance is added. However, we might not need auto scale group. The only concern is scoping variable per instance.